# convergence of $\int _1^{\infty} \sin\big(\mathrm{e}^x(x-2)\big)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

**Question:**

$$\int _1^{\infty} \sin\big(\mathrm{e}^x(x-2)\big)\,dx$$

does this converge?
Wolfram|Alpha doesn't have an answer, and I would really know. We tried to use Dirichlet and substituting with $t=e^x$. But couldn't continue

Comment: I am inclined to believe that it converges. The reason is because the wave oscillates quicker and quicker as $x$ grows. And so any next area under the curve is smaller than the previous area above the curve, and vice versa. The sum of these area's could be seen as an alternating series that meet the prereqs for converging. I put this answer as a comment rather than as an answer as I don't have proof nor do I have an outcome for this intergral.

Comment: Mathematica gives $-0.660469194672905149$

Comment: It should be obvious that it does, using imranfat's reasoning. No need to be fancy ...

Comment: At infinity, $\sin (e^x (x-2))$ behaves like $\sin e^x$. If $e^x=u$, then the integral becomes $\int^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u}\, du$, which is known to converge (but not absolutely).

Comment: See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show the convergence of 
$$\int _3^{\infty} \sin\big(\mathrm{e}^x(x-2)\big)\,dx$$
This is of the form
$$\int _a^{\infty} \sin\big(f(x))\,dx$$
Note that we have 
$$\int _a^{N} \sin\big(f(x))\,dx = \int _a^{N} (f'(x)\sin\big(f(x))) \times {1 \over f'(x)}\,dx$$
Now integrate by parts in the right-hand expression, then let $N$ go to infinity...